# Ajax returning to home page after response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

Sorry if I am so dumb on this.

I am just trying functionalities before having a proper structure.

In input page while clicking login it should call a ajax jsp.
I printed it in alert to verify.
After printing it. it goes back to the home page.

This is my welcome page.
`http://localhost:8080/Example/`

After alerting,it goes back to
`http://localhost:8080/Example/?`

I tried it in Spring MVC

Spring_servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   ">
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.ksv" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"  
    cache-period="31556926"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Controller

```
package com.ksv;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller  
public class Hello {  
    @RequestMapping("/")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        System.out.println("454545");

        return new ModelAndView("index");  
    }  


    @RequestMapping("/loajax")  
    public ModelAndView helloajax(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse res)
    { 
        System.out.println("hjhjhjh");

        return new ModelAndView("loajax");  
    }
}
```

JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calm breeze login screen</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/logo.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css">
<script>  
   function doAjaxPost() {    
    $.ajax({  
     type : "Get",   
     url : "loajax",   

     success : function(res) {  
      alert(res);   
     },  
     error : function(e) {  
      alert('Error: ' + e);   
     }  
    });   

   }  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <br>
            <form name="vinform">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>
                <button id="login-button" onClick="doAjaxPost()">Login</button>
                <br>
                <h2>
                    <a href="inda.html">Create Account</a>
                </h2>
                <a href="inda.html">Forgot?</a><br> <br> <br> <span
                    id="ksv"> </span>

                <div class="img" align="center"></div>
                <h3>This area is used to describe something which can be later
                    decided</h3>

            </form>
        </div>

        <ul class="bg-bubbles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script
        src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/index.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there more code you can provide?

Comment: @wong2 I have added it.

Comment: url you are passing to ajax request is wrong...it should start with "http://localhost:8080/example/loajax" .
Also the syntax for controller /loajax is bit different for a ajax call .Please refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/) link for simple spring mvc ajax controller

Answer (score 0):

on Ajax do you want to change the page ?? 
Normally you return json or xml (only data realetd not html kinda stuff) kind of thing on ajax return method. What I can suggest you , for clean solution make another controller with annotation @RestController , define loadAjax function here, and return String there , it will work

```
@RestController
public class AjaxHandler {  

    @RequestMapping("/loajax")  
    public String serveAjax(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse res)
    { 
        System.out.println("hjhjhjh");
        return "loajax";  
    }
}
```

For simple and concept understanding I have given this type of example. Other wise you can do it same controller also.
Hopes it helps.